# Twitter integration problem

Tags: iphone

I am facing very weird problem in Twitter integration in my iPhone app.

I have created application my twitter developer account. Which I am using in my app for twitter text based post.

But I am always getting "Incorrect Signature" error when I test the application on **device**.

However this twitter developer application keys (API and SECRET) are working fine in following cases
1) If i test the application on simultar
2) If i use these keys with other application.

NOTE: I am using shareKit for sharing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things that work on the simulator but not the device end up being case sensitivity issues. The simulator is not case sensitive, but the device is. I've used share kit quite a bit of times and can't think of a spot where this could come up configuring it, but to check and make sure!